# Does scrapy user agent ignore custom data-attributes

Tags: python, html, scrapy, web-crawler, custom-data-attribute

[image: ON W3SCHOOLS]

It says user agents will ignore custom data-attributes. See image from *w3schools*
I'm curious, if scrapy is ignoring these tags as I'm getting empty list may be because of data-attributes `data-v-529299fa=""` used in the HTML.
Here is my source

```
 <a data-v-529299fa="" target="_blank" href="https://data.amica.com.pl/files/pdm_IO/SER_0019314_ART.pdf" 
 class="product-spec__file-link">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Operating manual AWDG7512CL_1140173 (PL)</font>
    </font>
</a>
```

And I want to scrape the href of anchor tag containing a pdf link.
So here is what I've tried

```
 pdfs = response.xpath('//a[@data-v-529299fa=""]/@href').extract()
# also 
 pdfs = response.css('a[data-v-529299fa=""]::attr(href)').extract()
```

and I got [] empty list. There are more than 1 pdfs so that's why I'm using extract().
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Scrapy does not remove any content from the response received from the server.

What that line means is that web browsers do not act on the content of those attributes, they do not change what they display based on its content (JavaScript code can do that, though).